# How to create a clickable button under the message?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I'm trying to create a Discord bot using Python and discord.py, but currently I want to create a "clickable button":

[image: example]

This is an example of the Dank Memer bot with buttons. How do I achieve this and add buttons under my messages?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, these are part of the new ["Message Components"](https://discord.com/developers/docs/interactions/message-components) in Discord. For discord.py, this is called a Button Component. This feature isn't available in the PyPi version of discord.py and is only available in the 2.0 rewrite on the master branch.

```sh
$ pip install git+https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py.git@master
```

But since discord.py is no longer maintained, perhaps look into one of the maintained forks such as nextcord, disnake, etc.

To use create a button on the dpy 2.0:

```py
view = discord.ui.View()
item = discord.ui.Button(style=discord.ButtonStyle.blurple, label="Click Me", url="https://google.com")
view.add_item(item=item)
await ctx.send("This message has a button!", view=view)
```

Or for more complicated features, you can subclass `discord.ui.View` instead:

```py
class ViewWithButton(discord.ui.View):
    @discord.ui.button(style=discord.ButtonStyle.blurple, label='Click Me')
    async def click_me_button(self, button: discord.ui.Button, interaction: discord.Interaction):
        print("Button was clicked!")


await ctx.send("This message has a button!", view=ViewWithButton())
```

Button reference for discord.py can be found here: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/master/api.html#button.

Answer (score 0):

Install discord.py master branch by doing

```
pip install git+https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py.git@master
```

For using ui/interactions refer [Official docs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/master/api.html).

You can find examples on https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/tree/master/examples/views